# Importing .sol files from an node_modules folder

Tags: solidity, solc

Did i miss something in configuration, or will this be fixed in an future version?

Best regards

```
# ls -al
Makefile
README.md
build
cmd
contracts
node_modules
package.json

# ls -al ./contracts
Wallet.sol
```

```
cat  ./contracts/Wallet.sol
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "openzeppelin-eth/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "openzeppelin-eth/contracts/token/ERC20/StandaloneERC20.sol";
import "openzeppelin-eth/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol";
import "zos-lib/contracts/Initializable.sol";

contract Wallet is Ownable {
    function transferERC20(IERC20 token, address to, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner returns (bool) {
        require(token.transfer(to, amount));
    }
}
```

```
# solc --abi --bin ./contracts/Wallet.sol -o ./build
./contracts/Wallet.sol:3:1: Error: Source "openzeppelin-eth/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol" not found: File outside of allowed directories.
import "openzeppelin-eth/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
^---------------------------------------------------------^
./contracts/Wallet.sol:4:1: Error: Source "openzeppelin-eth/contracts/token/ERC20/StandaloneERC20.sol" not found: File outside of allowed directories.
import "openzeppelin-eth/contracts/token/ERC20/StandaloneERC20.sol";
^------------------------------------------------------------------^
./contracts/Wallet.sol:5:1: Error: Source "openzeppelin-eth/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol" not found: File outside of allowed directories.
import "openzeppelin-eth/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol";
^--------------------------------------------------------^
./contracts/Wallet.sol:6:1: Error: Source "zos-lib/contracts/Initializable.sol" not found: File outside of allowed directories.
import "zos-lib/contracts/Initializable.sol";
```

Comment: If you're using `solc` directly, then you should run it from a path which is a **parent of all source files**. Alternatively, you can just use `truffle compile`. There's a long discussion about this issue in [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/2742).

Answer (score 5):

The reason for this error is that `truffle compile` does some path remapping magic to find files which are imported from the `node_modules` folder.

If you are using the command line compiler version of [`solc`](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.2/using-the-compiler.html#using-the-commandline-compiler), you need to provide it these path remappings yourself.

The following command should work if it is run from the same directory as the `node_modules` dir:

`solc openzeppelin-solidity/=$(pwd)/node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/ contracts/**/*.sol`

Notes:

1. The path mapped to must be an absolute path, so using `$(pwd)` in the example above enable that without having to type the full path.
2. I don't know how to make this generic to any directory within `node_modules` you need to do this for each npm installed project you import solidity files from.
3. If you're getting `File outside of allowed directories` errors, you can add the `--allow-paths $(pwd)`.

See the [docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.2/using-the-compiler.html#using-the-commandline-compiler) for more info.

Comment: I had to replace `openzeppeling-solidity` with `@openzeppelin` on both occasions (April 2023). Also `$(pwd)` doesn't work in Windows and since I'm running solc in docker desktop, I had to replace it with my hardcoded dir in the container.