# solc --userdoc --devdoc NFTMarketplace.sol "NFTMarketplace.sol" is not found

Tags: solidity, solc, natspec

When I tried to generate Documentation with `solc --userdoc --devdoc NFTMarketplace.sol` I get the error `"NFTMarketplace.sol"`. It seems like solc cant find the path to my smart contract. I have spelled the contract name right.
Here is the path: `theim@MSI:~/fåjobb/nftmarketplace`.
[image]

Im running solc version: `0.8.16+commit.07a7930e.Linux.g++` and `pragma solidity ^0.8.7;` inside `NFTMarketplace.sol`.

I have also tried to run `solc --userdoc --devdoc NFTMarketplace.sol` with the path `theim@MSI:~/fåjobb/nftmarketplace/contracts` I then get a problems with OpenZeppelin:

```
Error: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol" not found: File not found. Searched the following locations: "".
 --> NFTMarketplace.sol:5:1:
  |
5 | import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Error: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol" not found: File not found. Searched the following locations: 
"".
 --> NFTMarketplace.sol:6:1:
  |
6 | import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Error: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol" not found: File not found. Searched the following locations: "".
 --> NFTMarketplace.sol:7:1:
  |
7 | import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Error: Source "hardhat/console.sol" not found: File not found. Searched the following locations: "".
 --> NFTMarketplace.sol:9:1:
  |
9 | import "hardhat/console.sol";
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem.

Using those resources:

- https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/natspec-format.html#documentation-output
- https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.14/using-the-compiler.html#base-path-and-import-remapping
- https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/solidity-compiler-solc-path-remappings-for-openzeppelin-contracts/2182
- [Importing .sol files from an node_modules folder](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/71222/importing-sol-files-from-an-node-modules-folder/79406#79406)

for those imports:

[image: my imports]

I tried some things and ended up with a working solution:

```
solc --userdoc  @openzeppelin=[REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_ABSOLUTE_PATH]/marketplace_foundry/lib/openzeppelin-contracts ./src/custodial/MarketplaceCustodial.sol
```

*Note that I'm using **foundry**, so if you're using **hardhat** or **truffle** you'll have to redirect the path to the* `/node_modules/` folder.