# --solc --userdoc --devdoc File not found. Searched the following locations: ""

Tags: solidity, solc, documentation, natspec

When trying to generate **user documentation** and **developer documentation** from the NatSpec of a smart contract with `solc --userdoc --devdoc MarketPlaceCustodial.sol` by following the [official documentation instructions](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/natspec-format.html#documentation-output)

[image]

It couldn't find the file.

[image: file not found]

By providing the relative path :

`solc --userdoc --devdoc ./src/custodial/MarketplaceCustodial.sol`

It detected the file but returned the **Error**:

`File not found. Searched the following locations: ""`

This time not finding the path to the **openzeppelin** folder

[image: openzeppelin path not found]

All remappings are in place and working well with **vscode** and **foundry**, however `solc` doesn't seem to detect them.

How to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using those resources:

- https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.14/using-the-compiler.html#base-path-and-import-remapping
- https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/solidity-compiler-solc-path-remappings-for-openzeppelin-contracts/2182
- [Importing .sol files from an node_modules folder](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/71222/importing-sol-files-from-an-node-modules-folder/79406#79406)

And trying different things I came up with this working solution:

```
solc --userdoc --devdoc @openzeppelin=[REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_ABSOLUTE_PATH]/lib/openzeppelin-contracts ./src/custodial/MarketplaceCustodial.sol
```

It works perfectly. I redirected it to .json file with `> doc.json`:

[image]

*Note that I'm using **Foundry**, so if you're using **Hardhat** or **Truffle** you'll have to redirect the path to the* `/node_modules/` folder.